# Why does the fructose monomer in sucrose appear different from isolated fructose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, carbohydrates

I understood that the representation of fructose is:

[image]

But during the formation of sucrose:

[image]

How did fructose, whose representation is given in the first picture, turn out to be different in the second. I tried to visualize myself rotating the molecule but the position of oxygen changes and it doesn't match with the one in sucrose.

Comment: Hint: Draw a vertical line/axis on your first diagram, connecting the oxygen to the middle of the C3-C4 bond. Then rotate the molecule 180 degrees counter clockwise. Now compare this with the fructose residue in sucrose ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ah, a (fairly) common conundrum that assails us Chemistry students when we start Biochem. ;-)

At first glance, the fructose molecule in your first picture, and that in the second picture appear to have different conformations:

> [image]
>   [image]

Believe me, they're the same. "How?" you ask? Stay with me here (it requires a little imagination):

Draw a vertical line/axis on your first diagram along the plane of the furanose ring, connecting the oxygen atom at the apex, right down to the middle of the C3-C4 bond. Then rotate the molecule 180 degrees *counter-clockwise*.

Now compare this with the fructose residue in sucrose.

(*I lack the necessary Org. Chem. sketching tools to depict this... apologies*)

---

If you weren't able to wrap your head around "rotation" bit, then, let's assign locant numbers to the carbon atoms in the two diagrams and *then* compare them:

> [image]
>   [image]
>
> <sub>I've drawn them tiny, my bad</sub>

Must've clicked by now ;)